# Pass PHP variable to fancybox iframe

Tags: php, variables, iframe, fancybox

I do see that there are several questions on this topic, however I have not been able to find an answer specifically for this situation. Other than what is included in fancybox, I do not have any javascript/jquery written as I do not know them.

I am writing the site in PHP. I have a button that opens a fancybox iframe, which is just a php page. That iframe needs a variable from the page it was clicked on from.

I have attempted to put it in the URL and use a $_GET, but I get a blank white page when opened through fancybox. Manually navigating to the page the iframe was supposed to open works.

Any ideas?

EDIT: Previously attempted code added

```
<a class='fancybox fancybox.iframe' href='ban.php'><button type='button' class='btn btn-danger btn'><i class='icon-remove icon-white'>&nbsp;</i>Ban User</button></a>
```

Iframe is being created like this, nothing fancy just a bootstrap button with a hyperlink.

```
 <a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" href="ban.php?client=<?php echo $clientid?>"><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn"><i class="icon-remove icon-white">&nbsp;</i>Ban User</button></a>
```

I would like to use the $_GET method and do something like this, but i get a blank page. I found out that when you add a question mark to a URL in fancybox - it makes the page blank. Chrome's console leaves this message: "Blocked a frame with origin "http://yourwebsitehere.com" from accessing a frame with origin "null".  The frame requesting access has a protocol of "http", the frame being accessed has a protocol of "data". Protocols must match."

```
<?php 
$goodURL = "ban.php" . urlencode("?client=" . $clientid);
echo "<a class='fancybox fancybox.iframe' href='$goodURL'><button type='button' class='btn btn-danger btn'><i class='icon-remove icon-white'>&nbsp;</i>Ban User</button></a>"?>
```

So I tried this, to get around the question mark problem - but I now get a "You don't have permission to access /ban.php?client=2 on this server."

EDIT 2: Added iframe stuff, the second piece of code does not generate an actual iframe in the fancybox popup.

Generated Iframe from last result

```
<iframe id="fancybox-frame1377582210185" name="fancybox-frame1377582210185" class="fancybox-iframe" frameborder="0" vspace="0" hspace="0" webkitallowfullscreen="" mozallowfullscreen="" allowfullscreen="" scrolling="no" src="ban.php%3Fclient%3D2"></iframe>
```

This is how that iframe is generated by fancybox

```
<iframe id="fancybox-frame{rnd}" name="fancybox-frame{rnd}" class="fancybox-iframe" frameborder="0" vspace="0" hspace="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen' + (IE ? ' allowtransparency="true"' : '') + '></iframe>',
```

Comment: I have tons of ideas but without seeing some code - it'll be useless...

Comment: I've added some previously attempted code and what I have currently.

Comment: I don't see any iframe in your code...

Comment: The iframe is being created by a jquery script called fancybox. The <a> tag is what it's looking for. I've also added a message to the post on what chrome's console leaves under the second piece of code.

Comment: I understand. I need to see the generated code that holds the declaration of the iframe.

Comment: added generated iframe and the source of it.

Comment: Let me add to this that the iframe not being generated seems to only be happening in chrome. IE, FF, and Opera seem to generate that iframe. This is what chrome's console left me. "Blocked a frame with origin "http://yourwebsitehere.com" from accessing a frame with origin "null". The frame requesting access has a protocol of "http", the frame being accessed has a protocol of "data". Protocols must match."

Comment: you got your answer: when using an iframe you have to use the same protocol, for example, if your page is served from HTTPS you can't call an iframe using HTTP.

Comment: I do see that, however at least from what I can see there should be no change in protocol.

Comment: As a workaround, I would copy the generated html of the iframe, fix the protocol, and "hard-code" it into my code (don't let jQuery/fancybox generate it).